# A famous cycling Race, Place or Climb beginning with the letter "D"

Tags: racing, climbing

I'm trying to think of either a famous cycling town, race or climb that begins with the letter "D" but I'm having problems coming up with any and google isn't much help either.

So I thought I'd open it up to the masses.

---

EDIT:
I'm using the name as a codeword for a project I'm working on, so Dauphine it is.  I've already had Alpe d'Huez, Big Bear Lake, Cairn O'Mount so far.

Comment: Do you at least know what continent?

Comment: Are you maybe thinking of a French pass such as Col d'Izoard?

Comment: Preferably Europe but it doesn't need to be, there are some great climbs in the USA too.  

I did think of using one of the french cols like d'Izoard or d'Huez but I kind of felt like that was cheating.

Comment: What's the context - are there going to be 25 other questions for the other letters?

Comment: I'm using the name as a codeword for a project I'm working on, sorry I should've included that in the question, I'll edit now

Comment: wonderful, so now we all need to start racking our brains for something beginning with "E" in time for your next project!

Comment: @PeteH - absolutely!!

Comment: @Neil well they did climb Etna in the giro this year or last, but hardly a classic! Or am I thinking of Versuvius?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently i can't just write Dauphiné Libéré because that's not enough letters to constitute a proper answer on StackExchange

Comment: How didn't I think of this!!?!?  Awesome, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Flüela Pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fl%C3%BCela_Pass) starting in **Davos** Switserland, going to Nauders / Austria:

Or, for more alpine chic: the [Albula pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albula_pass) between **Davos** and Sankt Moritz.